VMWare workstation 17 pro Ubuntu 24.04 VM installation stuck
I have a Ubuntu VM running on VMWare Workstation Pro and when I’m installing Ubuntu, the “acquiring and extracting image” step takes forever (it has already been more than half an hour). I think this is a problem since I’ve installed Ubuntu on Hyper-V before and this step just took 3 minutes.
Host:
10-core Intel Core 12 i7 CPU
16GB RAM
Guest:
4 cores/processors
4GB memory
I think that’s enough hardware?

(I used Google translate.)
While your virtual machine is selected,
From the menu: VM > Settings (or Ctrl+D)
In the Hardware tab,
Select the Display,
Deselect Accelerator 3D graphics.
